# gulp-sass is very slow in gulp 4

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

After updating the gulp version to gulp 4, gulp-sass is taking much time to watch and compile scss. It was fast with gulp version 3.9.1. 
Gulp-sass version is 2.3.2.
Is there any solution?

Note: Removing the sourcemaps didn't help.